# Backbone.js templating requiring invalid html in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js

tl;dr : In my template file, if I don't have invalid html, the template won't display in Phonegap.

The HTML for my index looks like this:

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div data-role="page">
      <a href="#login" id="clickme">Click to go to Login</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```

My template file is (currently) this simple:

```
<div data-role='content' id='loginpage'>
this is a test
</div>
```

The problem is, when I try to display that template using this Backbone code:

```
var LoginPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      this.template = _.template(tpl.get("login"));
      console.log("Got Login Template");
      console.log(this.template);
    },

    render: function(e){
        console.log("rendering login page with the following user");
        console.log(this.model);
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
        this.mainView = new LoginView({ el: $("#loginpage", this.el), model: this.model });
        this.mainView.render();
        return this;
    }
});

var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
    },

    render: function(e){
        console.log("rendering login view");
        return this;
    }
});
```

It doesn't work.

The REALLY interesting part, is if I add a single opening or closing tag with no valid partner to my template file, it displays perfectly.  It can be a closing `div`, an opening `table`, an opening `label`, a closing `p`, etc.  So far any tag I have tried makes it work as long as that tag is invalid.

soooo......wtf?
I should point out that it works either way in Chrome.

**EDIT**

This is what `tpl` does, and it appears that the error is somehow happening here.  If the HTML is valid, it isn't loaded.

```
tpl = {

    // Hash of preloaded templates for the app
    templates: {},

    // Recursively pre-load all the templates for the app.
    // This implementation should be changed in a production environment. All the template files should be
    // concatenated in a single file.
    loadTemplates: function (names, callback) {
        var that = this;

        var loadTemplate = function (index) {
            var name = names[index];
            console.log("Loading " + name);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'templates/' + name + '.html',
                data: {},
                success: function (data){
                    that.templates[name] = data;
                    index++;
                    if (index < names.length) {
                        loadTemplate(index);
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                async: false
            });
        };

        loadTemplate(0);
    },

    // Get template by name from hash of preloaded templates
    get:function (name) {
        console.log('getting ' + name);
        var temp = this.templates[name];
        console.log('got it!');
        return temp;
    }

};
```

Comment: Nope.  In fact it runs through my other code and displays all the console.log messages I would expect....just doesn't change the display.

Comment: Ah, wait a second, your question made me go back and look.  It doesn't run through all the comments (when the html is valid).  I'll have to figure out where it stops and why.

Comment: The error is happening at `_.template()` and it is `{"message":"'undefined' is not a function"}`.  So when my HTML is valid, that means `tpl.get` (which has all my templates loaded into an array when my application launches) is returning undefined.

Comment: I think you should add this function's code in your question, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the more of less similar issue with backbone template when I run it in device, I changed the loadTemplate method to following and it resolved the issue.

```
var loadTemplate = function (index) {
            var name = names[index];
            console.log('Loading template: ' + name);

            var data = $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: 'tpl/' + name + '.html', async: false}).responseText;
            that.templates[name] = data;
            index++;
            if (index < names.length) {
                loadTemplate(index);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This seems to have solved my problem (so far).  I wish I understood why. :(

Answer (score 0):

James.

```
<div data-role='content' id='loginpage'>
this is a test 
</div>
```

Sorry, is it a template, that you really use for the LoginPage view? But you call the `template` method with a `model` as a parameter. I'm confused.
So I think here is the problem. Try to change from `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));` to `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));`